ERRORED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST when trying to setup Lighthouse CI on Github
I'm posting here because I'm completely stuck on an issue with Lighthouse in GitHub CI
Here are the essential links:

lighthouserc.js = https://gist.github.com/cuzureau/eee71c12958f2b4ada1952bc755972d8
lighthouse.yml = https://gist.github.com/cuzureau/cd6f1981f5e7af201565b88df487143e
github errors = https://gist.github.com/cuzureau/4850575cfb5c667761ebb0a45466fd14

Here's the situation:
I'm trying to integrate Lighthouse to analyze my project's performance directly in GitHub CI.
I've set up the necessary configuration files. Everything seems correct (at least at first glance).
When the CI runs, the server starts properly and makes the site accessible via localhost. However, Lighthouse can't access this site.
The errors encountered:

ERRORED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST: it seems that Lighthouse is trying to access a site that isn't responding correctly, probably because it can't find anything at the localhost address.
404 Error: when Lighthouse tries to run its tests, it can't retrieve the expected document, which blocks the entire process.

I'm pretty sure this is an issue related to the fact that GitHub Actions doesn't allow direct access to a local server (for example, if localhost:3001 is running in the environment). So Lighthouse logically fails.
What I've tried:

Verifying that the server launches correctly before Lighthouse is called.
Checking the Lighthouse documentation for GitHub CI, but I haven't
seen anything that precisely matches my problem.
Adding delays to ensure the server is ready, without success.

Has anyone encountered this kind of problem before? Maybe there's an issue with my configuration, or I'm missing something obvious? Any help or leads would be welcome!
Thanks in advance for your ideas and feedback :)
